# Useful algorithm for making index file

Tags: algorithm, file, indexing, binary

.Hello.

Disclaimer: I'm not asking for a code. I'm trying to think of a solution for my problem, but can't figure out the algorithm.

My struct is a student, with string name and integer of average.

Say I have file named "file1.bin", that starts with an integer "X", and then X structs that are built: integer "Y" (length of name), Y-length string, and integer "average".

I have made an array of structs with all the details in the file.

Now, what I want to do, is to have an index file, that holds the indexes of the students, BUT I want to the indexes to point students sorted by average (low to high).

[image]

In this example, we have 3 students: Mike (80), Sam (100), Su (70).
When I open the binary file, I have the number of students. That's why we start at index 1.
Then, I want to reach Su's data, so I go to index 10.
Then, I want to read Mike's data, so I go to index 1.
Then, I want to read Sam's data, so I go to index 6.

Now, to my question, how can I make that efficient?
I was thinking about adding a value to the structs, but I'm not allowed to do that.

I was thinking about merge-sorting the whole employee array, but I can't think of anywhere it can take me.

I need to calculate the indexes file before the changes, and then somehow get to know where each index should be placed.

Does anyone have any idea how I can do that?

BIG thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't understand your index values. If I understand your description and count correctly, Mike is at index 1 and occupies 6 cells, so Sam starts at 7 and occupies 5 cells, and finally Su starts at 12 and occupies 4 cells. To me, it should be 1, 7, and 12 instead of 1, 6, and 10.

Comment: And: do characters and integers really occupy the same number of bytes in your file?